# How to link to a new CMS page from the category menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-url-rewrite

I created a new category and a new CMS page (with a questionnaire form) and now I would like to make it work so that when someone clicks on the category - it will NOT load the category page but instead the CMS page.

I found this:

Catalog > URL Rewrite Management > Add New URL Rewrite > then I select the category and then the page to create a Custom rewrite comes up but the "Target Path *" is grayed out with the URL of the category.

**How can I make it so that the category actually redirects to the CMS page?**

> Magento 1.9.1
>
> ### > Porto theme

*The solution by Steven J works - thank you! The only thing to mention is - you may have to go to Custom Design and set Page Layout = 1 column. I had to do this because it threw the formating of the page off...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a redirect, copy your CMS page content into a Static Block.

In the `Manage Categories` area, open your category, then open the `Display Settings` tab.

Change `Display Mode` to `Static Block Only`- then select the block you saved with your CMS page content in it.

Now the category page will load your information as it would a plain CMS page.

Comment: This works - thank you! The only thing to mention is - you may have to go to Custom Design and set Page Layout = 1 column. I had to do this because it threw the formating of the page off...

Comment: @Allysin I did not include that because some still use the columns for navigation and other features. It's more of a preference but definitely good to mention for others. Glad it worked for you